# Can protein modeling and simulation be used in developing a marketable product?

Tags: molecular-modeling, proteins, atomistic-simulation

As we all know computer science, electrical engineering, etc. knowledge can be used in developing software and electronics/electrical products that can be sold to end-users (B2C).

Can protein modeling and simulation be used to develop such products other than drug discovery?

Or, is it just about scientific/academic research meant for B2B clients?

Comment: Anywhere that experimentation can make money, so too can modeling and simulation if it is as accurate. There is big money in proteins. It doesn't even need to be as accurate, if it can save time, it has a market.

Comment: Potentially relevant: [Current methods and applications in computational protein design for food industry](https://doi.org/10.1080/10408398.2019.1682513)

Comment: You can use protein modeling/simulation to develop specific biomarkers.

Comment: @Camps it sounds like you could expand that into an answer?

Comment: No response to any of the comments?

Comment: @NikeDattani, Noh! I lost interst.

Comment: No problem, and thanks for letting us know! We can re-open the question any time if you re-gain enough interest. You can just ping me in a comment here :)